# How to access style variants and discretionary ligatures in a specific font?

Tags: fontspec, opentype

I am using MinionPro for my document (LuaLaTeX with `fontspec`). The font provides for a number of optional ligatures and glyph variants. Here's part of my font setup:

```
\setmainfont{MinionPro}[
UprightFeatures     = {
                              Numbers = { Proportional, OldStyle },
                           RawFeature = { +dlig,+cswh},
                       },
]
```

Are these considered "style variants?" How do I get LuaLaTex to use them automatically?

Forcing the Unicode chars doesn't seem like a viable long term solution:

`A Choral^^^^e08f fo^^^^e0da th^^^^e08f \emph{Medulla Oblongata}, Arranged i^^^^e0b2 Blood`

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzpnA.png]

Comment: See [the `fontspec` manual.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) E.g., an alias for `+dlig` is `Ligatures=Discretionary`, and there is a `Swash=` option as well.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what `RawFeature = { +dlig,+cswh}` in my example code does?

Comment: The `+cswh` feature is equivalent to `Contextuals=Swash`. Your font might support `Style=Swash` (`+swsh`), or `Contextuals=Final`.

Comment: If it doesn’t support any OpenType feature like that, but you know the codepoints, I suppose you could write a `Mapping=` file or an expl3 regex search-and-replace.

Comment: I unfortunately do not have the font to test.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep testing. The  `fontspec` manual (p. 39) mentions `Contextuals=WordFinal` which looks promising.

Comment: `otfinfo -f /path/to/font` should tell you which features it supports.

Answer (score 4):

Not every font family supports every possible feature, and not every font within a family supports the same features. Minion Pro, for example, has no `fina` feature (that’s what `Contextuals=WordFinal` requests), and it has `cswh` only in the italic.

In the case of Minion Pro, the final swashes are defined as `ss02`. That was the designer’s choice; they could have been defined as `fina` or something else altogether. You can’t learn the details of individual fonts from the `fontspec` manual; instead, you need to study the output of `otfinfo` and examine the font in a program such as [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/).

The following works in `xetex` (you can restrict these features to the upright if you like):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}[
  Ligatures=Rare,
  Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},
  StylisticSet={1,2}]
\begin{document}
A Chorale for the \textit{Medulla Oblongata,} Arranged in Blood
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

For reasons which aren’t entirely clear to me, it fails in `luatex`. I’m not terribly surprised, because I’ve never had luck with the initial, medial, and final variants of other fonts in `luatex`. But give me time, and I’ll find a way to re-create the feature with `\directlua{...}`.

*Edit:* As DG' commented, one can avoid the work of re-creating this feature for `luatex` by specifying `Renderer=Harfbuzz`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this and confirming an issue with LuaTeX. Since I only need this in a handful of places anyway I am treating it as the learning experience it is and simply specify the glyphs for the time being (regular expressions FTW.) No need for you to sink any more time in this, really :)

Comment: +1 nice answer. LuaHBTeX displays the swashes, if you set `Renderer=Harfbuzz`

Comment: @DG' Thanks! Much easier than re-creating the feature!